# Facing problems in creating conditional columns in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I want to create an SSRS report, I had dynamic Columns grouped by those questions have answers as well.

This is my current report.

[image]

This is what I want to do.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible , like adding conditional columns are not possible in  SSRS for that you have to use power BI.